# Odoo11 Settings Dashboard error in debug mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

When I am in debug mode and try to go to Settings or click on Settings --> Dashboard, odoo shows

Action Error

Could not find client action 'web_settings_dashboard.main'.

As I see - it is frontend issue.

If I am not in debug mode - works fine. What could it be?

Odoo 11.0e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some of file or change in file from odoo addon
Check the module : `odoo/addons/web_settings_dashboard` 
This might help you

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
For test please make a copy of your database and update following modules: base, web.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation. In my case, I have a custom addon with a JavaScript part. My mistake was the function declaration

openerp.pos_refund_credit = function(instance, local) { ... }

instead of

odoo.define('pos_refund_credit', function(require){ .. }

Answer (score 0):

It happens mainly due to imports we do using require('namespace'). Remove those imports from your custom JS file.

This fixed my issue.